# Typescript - export module types

Tags: typescript

I have a d.ts file that looks like this

```
import * as lalo from './core';
/**
 * Using module augmentation
 */
declare module './core' {
    interface extraStuff {
        (this: any): void;
    }
}
export default lalo;
```

it is a module, say, called "module/lalo" 
So when I export like

```
import myLalo from "module/lalo"
```

myLalo can access all the methods and members, and ALSO, as a type (namespace?) all the types (interfaces and such) defined in the d.ts file.

I need though to do something like this in another file, lalo-toggle.ts; to toggle between the original module and the beta version

```
import _laloA from "module/lalo";
import _laloB from "module/lalo-beta";

export function getLalo() {
  return Math.random() > 0.5 ? _laloA : _laloB;
}
```

The issue though is that the methods and members of lalo are defined in the object returned by getLalo, but I cannot access the types, interfaces and such.

Any ideas how I can extend the module defined so it is available to consumers of lalo-toggle.ts?

Comment: Why do you create a d.ts file? You don't have to do any module augmentation for this. Just put the interface in another file and import it to both `lalo` and `lalo-beta`.

Comment: I missed to say the first file is a library, out of our control